# Mongodb, mongoimport, uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier : @(shell):1:15

Tags: database, mongodb

Getting the below error while importing a csv file in MongoDB database.

command:

```
mongoimport -d test -c FAQ --drop --type csv --file C:\Users\KUMA\Desktop\FAQ.csv --headerline --host localhost:27017 --authenticationDatabase admin --username 'iamauser' --password 'pwd123'

error:
2019-10-25T16:00:21.044-0700 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:15
```

Comment: This error is because you are trying to run `mongoimport` from within the `mongo` shell. The `mongoimport` command needs to be run from a Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate in command prompt where **mongoimport.exe** file exist. Then try running below command, you should also put .json file in the same direcotry.

```
mongoimport --jsonArray --db test --collection FAQ --file FAQ.csv
```